# Regex to match \a574322 in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have long string looking like this: \c53\e59\c9\e28\c20140326\a4095\c8\c15\a546\c11 and I need to find expressions starting with \a and followed by digits. For example: \a574322 
And I have no idea how to build it. I can't use:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\a\\d*");
```

because \a is special character in regex.
When I try to group it like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\)(a)(\\d)*");
```

I get unclosed group error even though there is even number of brackets.
Can you help me with this?

Thank you all very much for solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 4 `\`.

2 to indicate to regex that it is not a special character, but a plain `\`, and 2 for each to tell the Java String that these are not special characters either. So you need to represent it in code this way:

```
"\\\\a\\d*"
```

Which is actually the regex `\\a\d*`

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex:

```
\\\\a\\d+
```

**[Code Demo](http://ideone.com/p8bwlp)**

Since in Java you need to double escape the `\\` once for String and second time for regex engine.

Comment: the regex is actually `\\a\d+`. This is the content of the Java String as represented in code.

Comment: Yep, you're going to need some double quotes there.

Answer (score 3):

You have to change your regex to:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\\\a\\d+)");
```

The regex is:

```
(\\a\d+)
```

[image]

The idea is to escape a backslash and then also escape the backslash for `\a`, and match digits too.

Answer (score -1):

`\\(a)[0-9]+` this should work

you can't try your regexps on this page or some similar

http://regex101.com/

Comment: +1 because this is correct, but those parenthesized groups are not necessary.

Comment: (1) OP doesn't have problem with creating regex, but with writing it in Java. (2) your link should be connected to specific example, not tool which can test regexes, (3) you don't need to surround ``\\`` with parenthesis.

Comment: Im sorry to desagree but even when from context we can infer he is using java, he explicitly asked for a regexp that could solve his problem. So @Pshemo, thank you for your anotation about brackets but i would recommend you in the future to read more carefully the user´s qustions. And finally, my link its to promove him to work on his regular expresion instead of creating a question about such a trivial theme. And user2040251 i guess you are an admin and, im sorry, but i dont quite understand the propose of your comment. Thank you.

Comment: "he explicitly asked for a regexp that could solve his problem" yes, but IMHO to be more precise regex written in Java. If you take a look at question you will see that OP tried to write it as `"\\a\\d*"` and `"(\\)(a)(\\d)*"` which is showing that OP knows what should be written (how regex should work) but doesn't know how to write it because `"\\a"` is interpreted as `\a` (alert bell, `\u0007`) and attempt to separate ``\\`` with `a` using parenthesis didn't work because in `"(\\)"` OP actually escapes `)` which leaves `(` unclosed. So real problem is how to write ``\`` literal in Java regex

Comment: Regarding user2040251 comment it is not that he is admin. On Stack Overflow when user get sufficient reputation it gains some [privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) like [voting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) if some flags (like "not an answer", or "low quality answer") are correct or not. This user voted (IMHO wrongly) that flag put on your post was correct and decided to leave one of standard (build-in in system) comments which you can see above.

Comment: If he is asking for a regexp that could solve his problem, thats what i provided. I belive that if your interpretation problems lead you to often to downvote usefull comments, you should make an effort to try to understand or in any other case make your own answer instead of disrepecting other´s because your Humbble opinion. I understand how reg exp works, but thanks anyway for expending some of your time clarifying your point.

Comment: (1) "*I belive that if your interpretation problems lead you to often to downvote usefull comments*" I actually downvote answers (comments can't be downcoted) very rarely, 99% of my downvotes ware used on questions of type "giveMeTehCodes", not answers (2) "you should make an effort to try to understand" judging by answer OP accepted I understand his problem correctly (3) "*or in any other case make your own answer*" there is no need to post separate answer if I see correct ones.

Comment: (4) "*instead of disrespecting other´s because your Humble opinion*" I don't mean to disrespect anyone, if I see something that can be corrected or improved I am writing about it (believe it or not, usually people like it). If you feel offended then I am sorry, that really wasn't my intention.